Is it possible to show that $v_{p}(f(\alpha)) \in \frac{1}{r}\Bbb{Z}$, where $v_{p}(\alpha) \in \frac{1}{r}\Bbb{Z}$ and $f(\alpha) \neq 0$
Let $K/\Bbb{Q}_{p}$ be a finite extension. If $\alpha \in K \setminus \{0\}$.
It is given that, $v_{p}(\alpha) \in \frac{1}{r}\Bbb{Z}$, where $r \neq 1$. Now is it true that, $v_{p}(f(\alpha)) \in \frac{1}{r}\Bbb{Z}$, if $f(x) \in \Bbb{Z}[x]$. Here $p$ is a prime number, and to see the definition of $v_{p}(\alpha)$ look into this link.
Also note that $\alpha$ is not a root of $f$, that is, $f(\alpha) \neq 0$, otherwise  $v_{p}(f(\alpha)) = \infty$. I am not sure about the proof.
So, is this result true, or can a counter-example be given of this?

What is $\alpha$? An element of some algebraic extension of $\Bbb Q_p$?

All relevant information should be included in the post itself, rather than requiring readers to visit some other link to get it.


the Wikipedia link only defines integer valuations.


yes $\alpha$ is in some algebraic extension of $\Bbb{Q}_{p}$

Sorry, I updated the link.

Thanks for this comment. This is a clear counter-example. But actually, I assume that $\alpha$ is in some extension of $\Bbb{Q}_{p}$ and so its valuation is in $\frac{1}{r}\Bbb{Z}$. So can we say something for the general $r$?

No. Slightly upgrading the counterexample by user297024 from a comment (before $r=1$ was excluded in the question), take $r=2$,
$\alpha = p^{1/2} +p^{2/3}$
and $f(x)=x^2-p$.
